# How to we monitor the request coming to cloudfront with request and header information

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

Is there a way to log all the request and header information coming to Cloudfront. We have a situation where a site hits Cloudfront and returns http 200. We have one situation where requests generated from a specific source is sending http 400. So we would like to log the full request coming to cloudfront for analysis.

Comment: You can log it using lambda@edge viewer request.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-event-structure.html#example-viewer-request   , cloudfront access logs also show request fields

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html

Comment: Lambda@Edge with examples: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-event-structure.html#example-viewer-request